# How can I parse text with colon, tabs and line breaks

Tags: vb.net, parsing

I am not sure how I should put this question's topic. But I tried my best. Here is the problem:

I have text like

```
VPN:
    1:
        Address: 198.168.1.1
        Name: Tux
        Role: Dex
    2:
        Address: 198.168.1.2
        Name: Pti
        Role: JPT
```

and so on.....

How can I parse this properly. This list is a list of servers, there are 2 servers right now, there could be more than 20 of them. 
I think of splitting by line break, checking the number, 1, 2.... then after the number first find line with word Address, Name and Role and so on.....but I'd love to have input of some experts here at SO. I'm using VB.NET

Thanks.

Comment: Show us what you have tried already.

Comment: I tried of splitting by line break, checking the number, 1, 2.... then after the number first find line with word Address, Name and Role and so on.... do you have any better solution?

Comment: That seems reasonable.  Without seeing the code its impossible to tell why it isn't working.  I'd suggest posting your code and showing us what its output is and what the expected out put is.

Comment: I didn't say it isn't working. It works. But is there a better solution to it?

Comment: Oh.  Well that is a question best suited for codereview.SE.  SO doesn't deal with that kind of question.

Comment: So you don't have the solution.

Comment: Whether I do or not is irrelevant.  This site does not deal in questions of "better".  Better is purely subjective.  Now, if you are experiencing a specific, quantifiable problem - ask that here.  "Better" is handled by codereview.SE.

Answer (score 0):

I would take everything to the left of the first colon in each line, then select based on that string:  "Address", "Name", "Role", numeric value, or unknown. Then take everything to the right of the first colon as the value for that item. Every time you encounter a numeric value, begin a new record.

An alternative way to do this is with a regular expression, but it may be easier write and maintain just to code it.